# how to get related opportunities of a account by select list

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, selectlist

I have custom picklist in that have all account names when user select any account name from that list option you have to get related opportunities of that account with a checkbox should be displayed also with a single account record please help me i am new salesforce.I got a requirement

i had tried sample code

```
   VisualForce

   <apex:page controller="accountPickListController" tabStyle="Account">
   <apex:form >
   <apex:pagemessages />
   <apex:pageBlock title="Account Name Picklist">
   <apex:pageblocksection >
   <apex:selectlist value="{!AccountName}" id="tryme" multiselect="false"    
   size="1" >
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountNames}">
   </apex:selectOptions>
   </apex:selectList>
   </apex:pageblocksection>
   </apex:pageblock>
   </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
```

Apex code:

```
    public class accountPickListController {


    public  list<opportunity> lstoppor;
    public String AccountName {set;get;}
    public Boolean allBool {get;set;}
    public List<wrapperOpport> lstoppwrapper {get;set;}
    public List<wrapperOpport> lstoppwrapper1 {get;set;}

    public accountPickListController () {

    lstoppwrapper = new List<wrapperOpport>();

    List<Opportunity> lstoppor = [select name from opportunity where 
    account.name=:AccountName];

    for(Opportunity opps:lstoppor)
    {
    lstoppwrapper.add(new wrapperOpport(opps));

    }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to show list of related list of opportunities when someone selects an Account ?? Where is the "cases_table" you are rerendering in actionSupport? Plus also provide the test method of controller.

Comment: yes i want to display account related opportunities in a visual force page like wrapper class style means checkbox and record in a row i am tried man times i don't know who to get selected option.please help me with any code    @Santanu Halder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller class should be

```
public class OppControllerr {
public List<OppWrapper> myList = new List<OppWrapper>();
    public String selectedAcc{get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> accs{get{
        List<SelectOption> opps = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(Account a : [SELECT Id, name from Account limit 10])
        {
            opps.add(new SelectOption(a.Name, a.Name));
        }
        return opps;
    }}
    public PageReference refresh()
    {
        myList.clear();
        System.debug('in refresh'+selectedAcc);
        for(Account a : [select id, name, (select name from opportunities) from Account where name = :selectedAcc])
        {
            for(Opportunity opp : a.Opportunities)
                myList.add(new OppWrapper(false, opp));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<OppWrapper> getMyList()
    {
        System.debug('count'+myList.size());
        return myList;}
}
```

OppWrapper class:

```
public class OppWrapper {
    public Boolean selected{get;set;}
    public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
    public OppWrapper(Boolean selected1, Opportunity opp1)
    {
        selected = selected1;
        opp = opp1;
    }

}
```

And Visualforce page should be:

```
<apex:page controller="OppControllerr">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedAcc}" size="1">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!accs}"/>
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!refresh}" reRender="oppList"/>
</apex:selectList>
<apex:pageBlockTable id="oppList" value="{!myList}" var="o">
<apex:column value="{!o.opp.Name}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Customize it.

Comment: getting error @Santanu Halder

Comment: Mind pasting the error? And also customize the code as per your requirement, dont just blindly copy the code

Comment: i have just copy the code and i want to know the output of your program but it can't save show error have you tried our code before posting @Santanu Halder

Comment: Of course you wont be able to save the apex class, the class refers to OppWrapper class which I hadn't pasted till now. I thought you would customize it as per your need. Anyhow, its there now!Go for Ctrl C & Ctrl V.